# Fast floating point abs function

Tags: c, performance, floating-point, c99

What is the fastest way to take the absolute value of a standard 32 bit float on x86-64 architectures in C99? The builtin functions `fabsf` and `fabs` are not fast enough. My current approach is bit twiddling:

```
unsigned int tmp = *((unsigned int *)&f) & 0x7fffffff;
float abs = *((float *)&tmp);
```

It works but is ugly. And I'm not sure it is optimal?

**Please** stop telling me about type-punned pointers because it's not what I'm asking about. I know the code can be phrased using unions but it doesn't matter because on all compilers (written in the last 10 years) it will emit exactly the same code.

Comment: Don't you think that, if a faster way was available, the library providers would have already opted for it? How many times are you needing to do this per second that the blindingly fast library routines can't manage? You might also want to consider the possibilities that your method may not work with the "uncommon" values, such as `NaN`. I'd have to investigate to be sure but it's something you may need to consider.

Comment: What you do does break strict aliasing and you ought to use unsigned for bit twiddling, and of course an union

Comment: To be faster than `fabsf()`, code must comprise range, accuracy and/or portability.  Without @Björn Lindqvist providing,what is compromise-able and a test harness, the question is moot.

Comment: @paxdiablo i timed it, my version is faster than `fabsf` but perhaps not the fastest possible. My code correctly handles NaNs

Comment: @chux My code works correctly for all 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point numbers on x86 64. So, it turns out, your comment is what's moot.

Comment: Type punning `float` and `unsigned` violates [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) "Strict Aliasing Rules".

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist It is good you have provided the processor and `float` encoding.  Does code need to work on other platforms?  Which ones?

Comment: Both [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/ZYDjTW) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/E0XgUL) optimize `fabsf` to an `andps` instruction. What is your basis for saying it is not fast enough? Large optimizations can be done with algorithmic improvements to code, but microoptimizations are hugely context dependent. You should identify the specific compiler version and switches you are using and show source code with context—preferably a complete routine that can be timed, in code that shows `fabsf` is the bottleneck and why (it would be very unusual for `fabsf` to be the bottleneck in a piece of software).

Comment: Well, [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/buDQoO) generates the same assembly (`andps`) as `fabs`.

Comment: If it's not fast enough then I believe you can only make it faster by getting the abs of multiple values at once with SIMD

Answer (score 3):

Less standard violations:

```
/* use type punning instead of pointer arithmatics, to require proper alignment */
static inline float float2absf(float f) {
  /* optimizer will optimize away the `if` statement and the library call */
  if (sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    union {
      float f;
      uint32_t i;
    } u;
    u.f = f;
    u.i &= 0x7fffffff;
    return u.f;
  }
  return fabsf(f);
}
```

IMHO, **it would be safer to use the library function**. This will improve code portability, especially on platforms where you might encounter a non-IEEE float representation or where type sizes might differ.

In general, **once compiled for your platform, the library function *should* provide the fastest solution**.

Having said that, **library calls require both stack management and code jumps unless optimized away**, which - for a simple bit-altering function - could result in more then twice the number of operations as well as cache misses. In many cases, **this is avoidable by using compiler builtins**, which could be done automatically by the compiler (it can optimize library functions into inline instructions).

Your bit-approach is (in theory) correct and could optimize away the operations related to function calls, as well as improve code locality... although the same could be achieved using compiler builtins and optimizations.

Also, please note that your approach isn't standard compliant and it assumes that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`... I think that type punning using a union will improve that little bit.

In addition, using an inline function could work out like using a macro and make the code more readable. In addition, it could allow a fallbacks to the library function if type sizes don't match.

Comment: Library calls do not require “stack management” or “code jumps.” Compilers are permitted to optimize, and Apple LLVM 10.0.1 with clang-1001.0.46.4 for x86_64 optimizes `fabsf` to `andps` with no function call.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , this may be true in most but not all cases. When writing drivers and kernel modules, library functions can’t be / aren’t optimized by the compiler due to possible side-effects and the possibility that the function name doesn’t map to the library function (but rather maps to some other function). As I mentioned, IMHO, using the library function or compiler builtin should be proffered.

Comment: The kernel routine `log` is a nuisance due to its overlap with the standard library routine, but this individual name can be managed with `-fno-builtin-log`, so it is not necessary to disable compiler optimization for all math library routines, and this is not a problem for `fabsf`. Library calls do not **require** actual function calls in assembly language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - as mentioned, I generally agree with you. I just don't think that library functions should be treated as sacred and I believe it's okay if OP wants to roll their own. My own experience shows that some library functions are slower than rolling your own, especially when hampered by locality and other portability concerns (such as `rand` and `atol`, where [my own versions, `fio_rand64` and `fio_atol`](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/b71d6e1e589e98994a7e6ac8bbe547b43b453542/lib/facil/fio-stl.h) perform better than the library's code).

Comment: @EricPostpischil - P.S. - I updated the answer to reflect the discussion.